# JavaFX Detect mutliple keyboard keys pressed simultaneously

Tags: java, javafx

As the title is saying I want to detect multiple keyboard keys pressed at the same time (*simultaneously*) and are being pressed (*simultaneously*) for a time period. I am trying to add multiple event handlers on the `Scene` but it doesn't work:

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler1 = key -> {
     //logic1 here
}

EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler2 = key -> {
     //logic1 here
}

getScene().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler1);
getScene().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler2);
```

**Why I want to do this:**

I  have some code and I want to resize a rectangle based on the `keyboard keys` pressed by the user.For example if the user is pressing `RIGHT ARROW` the rectangle is increasing to from right side and if the user is pressing `UP ARROW` the rectangle is increasing from the top side.

**The problem:**

But when the user is pressing [`RIGHT ARROW`] and [`UP ARROW`] simultaneously and keeping them pressed,the two actions above must happen together,and not only one of them.

Comment: The question is tagged with [javafx] thus it doesn't need to be stated in the title.

Comment: While including JavaFX in the title is a bit redundant when it's also in the tags, given the number of inappropriate answers that appear for JavaFX questions when they are also tagged with the Java tag, it's probably helpful to have it there. (Apparently people often don't read the tags...).

Comment: @James_D that makes sense, I was just going off what [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) says.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Perhaps a better option would be to omit the [java] tag and only use the [javafx] tag....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just manipulate some boolean properties:

```
private BooleanProperty upPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
private BooleanProperty rightPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

private BooleanBinding anyPressed = upPressed.or(rightPressed);

// ...

getScene().setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        upPressed.set(true);
    }
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed.set(true);
    }
});

getScene().setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        upPressed.set(false);
    }
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        rightPressed.set(false);
    }
});
```

If both keys are pressed simultaneously, both properties will be true, so you can register listeners with the boolean properties, or check them in an `AnimationTimer` as you need, e.g.:

```
double delta = .. ;

AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        if (upPressed.get()) {
            rect.setY(rect.getY()-delta);
            rect.setHeight(rect.getHeight() + delta);
        }
        if (rightPressed.get()) {
            rect.setWidth(rect.getWidth() + delta);
        }
    }
};

anyPressed.addListener((obs, wasPressed, isNowPressed) -> {
    if (isNowPressed) {
        timer.start();
    } else {
        timer.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason `AnimationTimer` is never starting...even when i hold UP ARROW for example pressed(to try this i have a `println()`inside `handle(long timestamp)`  but nothing is being printed).Maybe `BooleanBinding` isn't working...

Comment: @GoXR3Plus Try making `anyPressed` an instance variable, instead of a local one (obviously you will have to do the same with the properties). It is probably getting garbage collected when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Perfect,now it works but i need one more think,how can i have some delay into the `AnimationTimer` cause i need to not resize the rectangle so fast...

Comment: Just reduce the value of `delta`? The `timestamp` parameter is a timestamp in nanoseconds, so you can basically set a pixels/second speed and compute how much to change based on that if you want to be really precise. But it's also reasonably safe to assume it's getting called approximately 60 times per second.

Comment: This seems to fail if user presses the key while window is focused and releases it when it is not - application never gets the release event.