# How to make image move using arrows JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keypress, eventhandler

So basically I am importing an image of a car and try to make the car move by signalling up, down, left, right by using arrows key. Since JavaFX is less used compared to swing and awt, there are very few resources that I can find on internet. I am beginner and tried but confused when looking at the docs.

So here is what I have done:

```
public class Car extends Application{

  private int xcoor = 0;
  private int ycoor = 0;
  private int velx  = 0;
  private int vely  = 0;

  @Override 
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Image carImage = new Image("car.png");
    ImageView cImage = new ImageView(carImage);
    cImage.setFitWidth(120);
    cImage.setFitHeight(80);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(cImage);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 500);


    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
      @Override
      public void handle(KeyEvent event){

        //How to make the car move with arrow?

      }
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Car"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show(); 

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

}
```

Currently, I am figuring out the proper syntax in javaFX to handle the keypress, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "_Since JavaFX is very new ..._" Nice one.

Comment: @takendarkk I don't know the specific launch date but I do know that it is starting to replace swing and awt for GUI. should I change my wordings if it bothers you?

Comment: The first version was released in 2008 - the latest version has been out for almost 3 years :)

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the information btw @takendarkk

Comment: Don't make the spacebar apart of your "multiple keyboard keys pressed simultaneously". I recently played with this concept and it took me three days to figure out that some keyboard makers were lazy when it comes to the spacebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `layoutX` property

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
  @Override
  public void handle(KeyEvent event){

    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        cImage.setLayoutX(cImage.getLayoutX() + 10);
    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
        cImage.setLayoutX(cImage.getLayoutX() - 10);
    }
  }
});
```

You might also be interested in [JavaFX Detect mutliple keyboard keys pressed simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923658/javafx-detect-mutliple-keyboard-keys-pressed-simultaneously)

Comment: Thank you for the starter code, this is very close to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this ->

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e->{
    if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.RIGHT){
          //change the value of x and y appropriately 
          cImage.setLayoutX(x);
          cImage.setLayoutY(y)
    }
    //check for other arrow keys
});
```