# JAVAFX + SCENE BUILDER 8.3.0 problems with KeyEvent (this mysterious)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, keyevent

I really don't understand KeyEvent.
sometime work, sometime not.
in my first videogame(i try to make some simple game only for fun and improve my skill) work, i make all keybind to one unique method because if i do a second method(Keyevent) it doesn't  nothing.

Today i make a little fun program with a my wife head that run on the screen randomly
   and..when i doing the first KeyEvent it do nothing, like a dead method.

then i decided to find the cause at all cost. copy and paste the working KeyEvent method of previous program (position, root,name,nodes) and nothing to do. sometime work sometime not. 
when i do new project same result. sometime work sometime not.
i dont think if i post some pictures it serves something.
any tips? and sorry for my english. 
WINDOWS 8 JAVAFX SCENEBUILDER ECLIPSE 
the method is like this :       (obviously i write the name of the method in scenebuilder)

```
public void Press(KeyEvent event) {

        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {action14();}
        else {\\ do something  }event.consume();
}
```

event.consume(); was only a try

HERE the  code:

**MAIN**

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("prova1.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.show();
            scene.getRoot().requestFocus();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="384.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.Mycontroller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="1080.0" fitWidth="1980.0" focusTraversable="true" layoutX="-39.0" layoutY="-23.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@grass123.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="war" focusTraversable="true" layoutX="244.0" layoutY="96.0" onKeyPressed="#Press123">
         <image>
            <Image url="@giphy-tumblr.gif" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="alla" fitHeight="102.0" fitWidth="105.0" focusTraversable="true" layoutX="545.0" layoutY="574.0" onMouseClicked="#allaclic" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@faccino.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="base" fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="8000.0" layoutX="-671.0" layoutY="666.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Desktop/barra.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
public class Mycontroller<I> implements Initializable{
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void Press123(KeyEvent y) {
        if(y.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {war.relocate (50,50); }
        else {}
    }
    @FXML
    public  ImageView alla;
    @FXML 
    public  ImageView war;
    @FXML Circle cir=new Circle(40,40,40);
    public int random() {
        int a=0;a=(int) (Math.random()*300-300); 
        return a;}
    public void allaclic(MouseEvent o) {
        AnimationTimer time=new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                int x=0;x+=1;int y=0;y+=1;
                saluto(x,y);
            }
        };time.start();
        TranslateTransition tra=new TranslateTransition();
        tra.setNode(alla);
        tra.setToX(random());
        tra.setToY(random());
        tra.setCycleCount(1);
        tra.setAutoReverse(true);
        tra.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1.5));
        tra.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {allaclic(o);}
        });
        tra.play();o.consume();
        FadeTransition trans = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), (alla
                ));
        trans.setFromValue(1.0);
        trans.setToValue(.00);
        trans.setCycleCount(FadeTransition.INDEFINITE);
        trans.setAutoReverse(true);
        trans.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {t.consume();}
        });
        trans.play();
    }
    public void rotation() {
        RotateTransition rotate=new RotateTransition();
        rotate.setNode(alla);
        rotate.setByAngle(random());rotate.setFromAngle(random());
        rotate.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        rotate.setAutoReverse(true);
        rotate.play();
        int g=0;int y=0;saluto(g,y);
    }
    public void saluto(int x,int y) {
        if(alla.getBoundsInParent().intersects(163,160,15 ,75)) {  //something;
        }
    }
    //something}
    public void tempohey() {
        Timeline time=new Timeline();
        time.setAutoReverse(false);
        time.setCycleCount(1);
        KeyValue kv=new KeyValue(war.layoutXProperty(),200);
        KeyFrame kf=new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500),kv);
        time.getKeyFrames().add(kf);time.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post [mcve] please.

Comment: i get the message: you are not allow to post photo when i load.(or something similar... message disappears immediately

Comment: can u explain how i can put it here

Comment: [mcve] is about code. If you want to add image, use a web link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: nothing.. i lost 3 hours for try to post something.

Comment: nothing.. i lost 3 hours for try to post something. i think is my first time in my life that i cannot post. if i do image i get "u not allow to post image", if i copy paste or drag my code i get error. if i read the rule for put code (4 space etc,etc,) nothing work  after try to assemble 300 line of code with your rules. Now my question is how i can post some code here? i begin from start... please dont tell me read the rules that i re-read 800times. which is action to do for post even just 10 line of code? thank for attention

Comment: It is not **my rules**. I am a user just like you, trying to help. I assume that you can post as everyone else does. The code is far more important than a picture. 300 lines does not sound like [mcve].  Paste your code [here](http://www.browxy.com/)  (or a similar service) and post a link to it here as a comment. I will help you post it. Do the same with to the image you are trying to load using [tinypic](http://tinypic.com/) or alike

Comment: Thanks for  answer and im sorry for my angry comment.its20 hours that i study without pause. Tomorrow i put the code in your link :) its the first thought as i get up

Comment: BTW you can paste your code, select a whole block of code and click the code sample button **{}** on the toolbar. It will indent that whole code block 4 spaces.

Comment: thank but i do this infinite times :/ no work for me. i used your link

Comment: done. u see link of all code in the post. keyevent no work whit any setting i do.. but in previous project work fine with the same identical situation

Comment: Please read the content of [mcve]. Mcve does not mean dumping the whole code here.

Comment: Don't assign `onKeyPressed`  to the image ( remove `onKeyPressed="#Press123"`), but to the [scene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854855/3992939)

Comment: but if i write this in main, how i can get my image  in controller? remember i use scenebuilder FXML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and demonstrates a working key-event handler:

```
public class DrawImage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DrawImage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.getRoot().requestFocus();//key event needs focus
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**note the important comment about focus**

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class DrawImageController{

    @FXML ImageView war;

    @FXML
    public void press123(KeyEvent event){

        System.out.println("Key Pressed"); // print a message
        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {war.relocate (50,50); }
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" 
onKeyPressed="#press123"
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 

fx:controller="stackoverflow.DrawImageController">

    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="war" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" 
                layoutX="50.0" layoutY="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow-2/64/cat-rascal-icon.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**to make it mcve make images or any other resources available**

Comment: work now very  thanks, (work too the previous answer... scenebuilder was setting bad)   then for all that i understand is better bind all eventkey on the anchorpane(in this case) im right?

Comment: I believe this should be posted a new question with a [mcve] demonstrating what is not working